# Join related table of related table in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, join, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have a table, `dna_extraction_protocols` which contains data about DNA extraction protocols. A number of keys are occupied by `Incubation` objects stored on the `incubations` table. The incubations have a `duration_unit` key which contains a `MeasurementUnit` object, which is contained in the `measurement_units` table.

These tables are created like so:

```
class DNAExtractionProtocol(Protocol):
    __tablename__ = 'dna_extraction_protocols'
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'dna_extraction'}
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('protocols.id'), primary_key=True)
    sample_mass = Column(Float)
    mass_unit_id = Column(String, ForeignKey('measurement_units.id'))
    mass_unit = relationship("MeasurementUnit", foreign_keys=[mass_unit_id])
    digestion_buffer_id = Column(String, ForeignKey("solutions.id"))
    digestion_buffer = relationship("Solution", foreign_keys=[digestion_buffer_id])
    digestion_buffer_volume = Column(Float)
    digestion_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("incubations.id"))
    digestion = relationship("Incubation", foreign_keys=[digestion_id])
    lysis_buffer_id = Column(String, ForeignKey("solutions.id"))
    lysis_buffer = relationship("Solution", foreign_keys=[lysis_buffer_id])
    lysis_buffer_volume = Column(Float)
    lysis_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("incubations.id"))
    lysis = relationship("Incubation", foreign_keys=[lysis_id])
    proteinase_id = Column(String, ForeignKey("solutions.id"))
    proteinase = relationship("Solution", foreign_keys=[proteinase_id])
    proteinase_volume = Column(Float)
    inactivation_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("incubations.id"))
    inactivation = relationship("Incubation", foreign_keys=[inactivation_id])
    cooling_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("incubations.id"))
    cooling = relationship("Incubation", foreign_keys=[cooling_id])
    centrifugation_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("incubations.id"))
    centrifugation = relationship("Incubation", foreign_keys=[centrifugation_id])

    volume_unit_id = Column(String, ForeignKey('measurement_units.id'))
    volume_unit = relationship("MeasurementUnit", foreign_keys=[volume_unit_id])

class Incubation(Base):
    __tablename__ = "incubations"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    speed = Column(Float)
    duration = Column(Float)
    temperature = Column(Float)
    movement = Column(String) # "centrifuge" or "shake"

    #speed - usually in RPM - will refer to either centrifugation or shaking (See above)
    speed_unit_id = Column(String, ForeignKey('measurement_units.id'))
    speed_unit = relationship("MeasurementUnit", foreign_keys=[speed_unit_id])
    duration_unit_id = Column(String, ForeignKey('measurement_units.id'))
    duration_unit = relationship("MeasurementUnit", foreign_keys=[duration_unit_id])
    temperature_unit_id = Column(String, ForeignKey('measurement_units.id'))
    temperature_unit = relationship("MeasurementUnit", foreign_keys=[temperature_unit_id]

class MeasurementUnit(Base):
    __tablename__ = "measurement_units"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    code = Column(String, unique=True)
    long_name = Column(String)
    siunitx = Column(String)
```

Now, I would like to extract a Pandas dataframe, where I can get all the attributes of the `DNAPurificationProtocol` object, of a linked `Incubation` object, and of a linked `MeasurementUnit` object.

I have tried a number of approaches, and this one seems to work nicely for the first relationship:

```
sql_query = session.query(DNAExtractionProtocol, MeasurementUnit, Incubation) \
    .join(MeasurementUnit, MeasurementUnit.id == DNAExtractionProtocol.volume_unit_id) \
    .join(Incubation, Incubation.id == DNAExtractionProtocol.lysis_id) \
    .filter(tables[table].code == code)
```

But what to me felt like a logical extension:

```
sql_query = session.query(DNAExtractionProtocol, MeasurementUnit, Incubation) \
    .join(MeasurementUnit, MeasurementUnit.id == DNAExtractionProtocol.volume_unit_id) \
    .join(Incubation, Incubation.id == DNAExtractionProtocol.lysis_id) \
    .join(MeasurementUnit, MeasurementUnit.id == Incubation.temperature_unit_id) \
    .filter(tables[table].code == code)
```

Fails with:

`sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) ambiguous column name: measurement_units.id [SQL: u'SELECT protocols.type, dna_extraction_protocols.id, protocols.id, protocols.code, protocols.name, dna_extraction_protocols.sample_mass, dna_extraction_protocols.mass_unit_id, dna_extraction_protocols.digestion_buffer_id, dna_extraction_protocols.digestion_buffer_volume, dna_extraction_protocols.digestion_id, dna_extraction_protocols.lysis_buffer_id, dna_extraction_protocols.lysis_buffer_volume, dna_extraction_protocols.lysis_id, dna_extraction_protocols.proteinase_id, dna_extraction_protocols.proteinase_volume, dna_extraction_protocols.inactivation_id, dna_extraction_protocols.cooling_id, dna_extraction_protocols.centrifugation_id, dna_extraction_protocols.volume_unit_id, measurement_units.id, measurement_units.code, measurement_units.long_name, measurement_units.siunitx, incubations.id, incubations.speed, incubations.duration, incubations.temperature, incubations.movement, incubations.speed_unit_id, incubations.duration_unit_id, incubations.temperature_unit_id \nFROM protocols JOIN dna_extraction_protocols ON protocols.id = dna_extraction_protocols.id JOIN measurement_units ON measurement_units.id = dna_extraction_protocols.volume_unit_id JOIN incubations ON incubations.id = dna_extraction_protocols.lysis_id JOIN measurement_units ON measurement_units.id = incubations.temperature_unit_id \nWHERE protocols.code = ?'] [parameters: ('EPDqEP',)]`

Any idea how else I can get what I am looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The heart of the problem is that you are joining the same table twice. In SQL-land, the way you solve this is to alias one of them:

```
SELECT * FROM protocols
JOIN dna_extraction_protocols ON ...
JOIN measurement_units ON ...
JOIN incubations ON ...
JOIN measurement_units AS incubation_measurement_units ON incubation_measurement_units.id = incubations.temperature_unit_id
```

Same thing here:

```
sql_query = session.query(DNAExtractionProtocol, MeasurementUnit, Incubation) \
    .join(MeasurementUnit, ...) \
    .join(Incubation, ...) \
    .join(MeasurementUnit, ..., aliased=True) \
    .filter(tables[table].code == code)
```

If you need to return columns from or filter on the aliased table, you'll run into problems because you won't be able to disambiguate between the two. In that case you'll need to join to an explicit [`aliased()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/query.html?highlight=aliased#sqlalchemy.orm.aliased) construct.

```
IncubationMeasurementUnit = aliased(MeasurementUnit)
sql_query = session.query(DNAExtractionProtocol, MeasurementUnit, Incubation, IncubationMeasurementUnit) \
    .join(MeasurementUnit, ...) \
    .join(Incubation, ...) \
    .join(IncubationMeasurementUnit, ...) \
    .filter(tables[table].code == code)
```

Comment: I ma trying to use this [here](https://github.com/TheChymera/medaba/blob/ef69d57dbafa34a4d83402acc5aaba6f1a043c89/src/dbdata/fmri.py#L41-L46) but this does not retrieve the columns from the `measurement_units` entry linked by the `incubations` entry. I get the same number of columns with or without the last join, in fact. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: @TheChymera You didn't copy the example exactly. You're missing `IncubationMeasurementUnit` in the list of queried entities.